# how to insert the name of the file in the text?

Tags: environment-variables

I´m making bigwork-096.tex

The source of that file is

```
\begin{document}
  This source is very big.\\
  The name of this file is **????????**
\end{document}
```

What I must type instead ??????  to obtain the PDF with this result

This source is very big.\
The name of this file is **bigwork-096.tex**

Comment: The name of the current file is always contained in the macro `\jobname`. The extension `.tex` is omitted. so one has to say `\jobname.tex`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you very much for solve my question. May be duplicate, but I looking for before posting with no results. I think that  a little comment lika your is good to help other people.